# React-portal-popout DOM Error version ^1.9.3

Tags: reactjs, popup

I'm currently using "react-portal-popout": "^1.9.3", and when i popout it, following error message comes out.

"Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17."

Moreover, in my own 'index.js' file, I've already changed my 'index.js' file's DOM version to 18, and just those error comes out only when i used the popup library.

Will there be any way to solve this error?

Comment: You need to change both `react-dom` *and* `react` packages to 18...if you havent already. Did you mean package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From React18, react has a bit different structure for creating root element.
You'd need to change your index.js file like below;

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: I've already changed my 'index.js' as above. This error comes out from only when i execute React-portal-popout.

Comment: The latest version (1.9.3) of react-portal-popout has been developed on React 16. And inside this package, it used ReactDOM.render function which is not supported on React 18. Turns out, you'd need to downgrade your React version to 16 or customize the package for yourself if you want to keep using this package.

Comment: Ah,,,, thanks for confirming.
Also i was predicting that was due to version difference in react-portal-popout, and it was correct !
Again, thanks for your comment